# Has this gradient fill disappeared in Excel 2007 & 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I am drawing `column chart` in Excel 2007 & 2010:

[image]

The slides of my colleagues are all made in Excel 2003, they have a gradient fill as follows:

[image]

I really would like to fill the same style in my column chart, but it seems that no combination in the customizing window does this in Excel 2007 & 2010.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Where it says type, try selecting cylinder

Comment: There are `Linear`, `Radial`, `Path` and `Rectangular` types, there is no `cylinder` type...

Comment: then its a lost cause I'm afraid, they appear to have removed that functionality

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2007, with Insert > Charts > Column  - Clustered Cylinder:

[image: SU482704 example]